# How do i can call more than one gradle scripts into other gradle script

Tags: gradle

I am converting ant script to gradle.I have change following

```
<ant antfile="build.xml"
             target="clean"/>

task buildclean(type: GradleBuild)<< {
    buildFile ='build.gradle'
    tasks['clean']
}

task buildelocket(type: GradleBuild)<< {
    buildFile ='bussniess/build.gradle'
    tasks['elocket']
}
```

this gradle script is calling three more other gardle scripts.When i called buildclean task from other task under same gradle script it is not working properly

```
task callingtasks <<{
    tasks.buildclean.excute()
    tasks.buildelocket.excute()
}
```

How do i can call more than one gradle scripts into other gradle script

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two issues with your build scripts:

1. remove the "<<" in the buildclean and buildelocket task. << is a shortcut for doLast{} but buidfile and task property of tasks of type GradleBuild should be set in configurationphase not during execution phase:

   ```
   task buildclean(type: GradleBuild) {
       buildFile ='build.gradle'
       tasks << 'clean'
   }

   task buildelocket(type: GradleBuild){
        buildFile ='bussniess/build.gradle'
        tasks << 'elocket'
   }
   ```
2. For a number of reasons you should avoid executing tasks explicitly via execute(). Try

   ```
   task callingtasks(dependsOn: ['buildclean', 'buildelocket']){
   }
   ```

Comment: task buildall(dependsOn: ['cleanBusinessServices','dleisejbdoclet'] {
          }

Comment: I have added task buildall(dependsOn: ['cleanBusinessServices','dleisejbdoclet'] {}

Comment: I have added following in my script 
task buildall(dependsOn: ['cleanBusinessServices','dleisejbdoclet'] { } 
but it throws exception 


* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file 'C:\devel\amp\amp-build\build.gradle'.
Cause: startup failed:
build file 'C:\devel\amp\amp-build\build.gradle': 470: unexpected token: import @ line 470, column 1.
   import org.gradle.*
   ^

Comment: Can you please show me how i set buildfile and task property of type GradleBuild in configuration phase?

Comment: you just need to remove the "<<" from your original script. the rest is just fine. I think you missed a ")" in your comment

Comment: I've just updated the answer with the updated buildclean and builelocket definition